# Does System.IO.File encapsulates SMB1.0/SMB2.0?

Tags: java, c#, .net, windows, network-programming

I am new to SMB1.0/SMB2.0 and am trying to create a C# class library to encapsulate basic File/Directory operations like Copy, ReadAllText, Delete, etc., using https://github.com/TalAloni/SMBLibrary.

My questions are:

1. Is System.IO.File already encapsulate SMB1.0/SMB2.0 protocol, and do I not need to use 3rd party SMBLibrary?
2. I have written the following code to Move a file from one SMB share to another SMB share, but it only renames and does not Move the file from a source location to the target location. How can I do that?

```
  public bool Move(string sourceFilePath, string targetFilePath)
        {
            if (!CheckLoggedIn())
            {
                return false;
            }

            object fileHandle = null;
            _status = _store.CreateFile(out fileHandle,
                                       out FileStatus _,
                                       sourceFilePath,
                                       AccessMask.GENERIC_ALL | AccessMask.SYNCHRONIZE,
                                       FileAttributes.Normal,
                                       ShareAccess.Write,
                                       CreateDisposition.FILE_OPEN,
                                       CreateOptions.FILE_NON_DIRECTORY_FILE | CreateOptions.FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_ALERT,
                                       null);

            if (_status == NTStatus.STATUS_SUCCESS)
            {
                _status = _store.SetFileInformation(fileHandle, new FileRenameInformationType2()
                {
                    FileName = targetFilePath
                });

                _status = _store.CloseFile(fileHandle);
            }

            return _status == NTStatus.STATUS_SUCCESS;
        }
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with ‘java’?

Comment: @VGR because I could get helpful direction if someone worked on Java JCIFS https://www.jcifs.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, System.IO does not contain an SMB 1.0 or SMB 2.0 client.
2. In order to move file from one share to another, the client must read the content of the file from the source share, and then write its content to the second share. it must be copied in this manner (and then deleted from the source).

Answer (score 0):

I found **EzSmb** https://github.com/ume05rw/EzSmb library with which you could move files within same SMB share using the following code:

```cs
// ** SMB1 NOT Supported. **

//using EzSmb;
//using System;
//using System.Threading.Tasks;

// Get Node of file.
var file = await Node.GetNode(@"192.168.0.1\ShareName\FileName.txt", "userName", "password");

// Move to child folder path.
// ** Even if you don't change the file/folder name, write the name. **
var movedFile = await file.Move(@"FolderName\RenamedFileName.txt");

Console.WriteLine(movedFile.FullPath);
// -> 192.168.0.1\ShareName\FolderName\RenamedFileName.txt


// Get Node of folder.
var folder = await Node.GetNode(@"192.168.0.1\ShareName\FolderName\SubFolderName", "userName", "password");

// Move to Parent path.
var movedFolder = await folder.Move(@"..\RenamedSubFolderName");

Console.WriteLine(movedFolder.FullPath);
// -> 192.168.0.1\ShareName\RenamedSubFolderName
```